# How to merge two worksheets entirely -- with varying spreadsheet names, format, and worksheet titles

Tags: vba, excel, import

Alright so i'm working on making a "catch all" spreadsheet of sorts.

I work with customers who give us **schedules**, all in varying formats and appearances, but all in excel (.xlsx).

The goal is to be able to make an "excel tool" if you will, that with a click of a button i can navigate to the schedule i was given, and import it into the tool. Then from that tool, i can continue to use other VBA scripts (which i already have put together) to grab from other excel worksheets and therefore make the tool into a nicely put file with multiple sheets, including all of the customer information.

The problem i'm encountering is that i receive schedules from the customer with absolutely no consistency. They give the schedules random names, they sometimes don't use tables, and they rename the sheets all sorts of stuff. So far i've only been able to find a method to automate the merging of two spreadsheets, but it only works if the schedule has the same location, and names.

Any idea of any workaround on this?

Possibly a vba script that will open windows explorer, allow me to choose the excel sheet i need, and just import **everything** into the tool, all formatting and sheets **regardless** of the name(s) and quantity?

Comment: `Application.GetOpenFilename()` is a good place to start: for the rest of it you're going to need to provide more detail on exactly how variable the input files are.  There's no one "import file regardless of structure" method - it will need to be tailored to your inputs.

Comment: @Tim Williams -- 
So; unfortunately they vary in such a high degree that its hard to give exacts. Nevertheless, i'll do my best here. 

I think the difficult part is that they never name the sheets or worksheet itself altogether, any one name. For example sometimes we have "Schedule 10/06 facility 12345.xslx" other times its "Schedule 1.xslx". Additionally, the sheets themselves are never consistent. sometimes they name them "Schedule" and "Communication plan", other times they make just leave them at the default Sheet1, Sheet 2, and Sheet3.  Hopefully this made a little more sense

Comment: I think if possible, my goal would be to be able to choose a file; and import all sheets that exist on said worksheet.

Comment: You can either place all of the inputs in the same folder and loop over them, or use GetOpenFilename to select them.  As for sheet names, you could consider using position if the names are inconsistent, or look for common text on the sheets to decide which is which.  However you do it, you're going to need to write code, so I'd start on that and post back if you run into specific problems.

Comment: Alrighty so here's what i got so far.

Comment: Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select the HC File")
    If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)

    '~~> Copy STNHC Data from Health Check File
wb2.Activate
Sheets("STNHC").Select
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy

Comment: '~~> Paste STNHC Data to Tool
wb1.Activate

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "HEALTH_CHECK"
    Sheets("HEALTH_CHECK").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: Edit your question to include code - use the {} button to format.  And don't just post code: if there's some problem you're having with it then you need to describe that too.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so i've got:

```
     Sub HC_import()
            Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
            Dim Ret1
            Dim Ret2

            Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

            On Error Resume Next

            '~~> Get the Health Check File
            Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
            , "Please select the HC File")
            If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)

            '~~> Copy STNHC Data from Health Check File
        wb2.Activate
        Sheets("STNHC").Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Selection.Copy


            '~~> Paste STNHC Data to Tool
        wb1.Activate

            Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            ActiveSheet.Name = "HEALTH_CHECK"
            Sheets("HEALTH_CHECK").Select
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        '~~> Copy PatchETL Data to Tool
        wb2.Activate
        Sheets("PatchETL").Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Range("A:I").Select
        Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

This works well, assuming the sheet is **always called** "STNHC" -- i need something that works similary; but that will work regardless of what the sheets are called.

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly vague, however if I understand you correctly...  What if you take all of the excel files, put them in 1 folder, then write a simple vbs script to rename all files containing ".xls" in said folder to a consistent file name, then have the script go through the same files to rename all of the sheets to what you need i.e. "STNHC".  Then your files will be consistent to work with your existing tool?